# 'Order not found' exception error after paying with PayPal Plus in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

Lately we get these exceptions after user finishes checkout in Magento and uses PayPal Plus as payment method. Customer gets error page but payment is made and Magento order status is set to "payed".

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Order not found.' in app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/community/Iways/PayPalPlus/Model/Webhook/Event.php(254): Mage::throwException('Order not found...')
#1 app/code/community/Iways/PayPalPlus/Model/Webhook/Event.php(70): Iways_PayPalPlus_Model_Webhook_Event->getOrder(Object(PayPal\Api\WebhookEvent))
#2 app/code/community/Iways/PayPalPlus/controllers/IndexController.php(171): Iways_PayPalPlus_Model_Webhook_Event->processWebhookRequest(Object(PayPal\Api\WebhookEvent))
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Iways_PayPalPlus_IndexController->webhooksAction()
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('webhooks')
#5 app/code/community/BalkeTechnologies/StoreMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it? Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please check table `sales_payment_transaction`. `order_id` entry inserted properly or not (It's error because of order not found from current transaction).